Combination of tuples and nest the elements of these 2 tuples together im CPLEX
I have two tuples like this:
tuple Combination_L {
  int rooms;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int courses;
};


{Combination_L} L = ...;


tuple Combination_T {
  int days;
  int slots;
};


{Combination_T} T = ...;

So, I want to combine Tuples L and T to initialize the Tuple V.
And this Tuple Vl must be:
tuple Combination_L_T{
  int rooms;
  int days;
  int slots;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int courses;
};

{Combination_L_T} Vl = {};
execute {
 for (var p in L){
   for (var q in T){
     Vl.add(<p.rooms, 
             q.days,
             q.slots, 
             p.instructors, 
             p.studentgroups,
             p.courses>);
   };
 }; 
};

So, I become a error warning "missing expression" by Vl.add.
Could you tell me please, how could I fix this error?. Thanks all!

I got it. I should not use <> in Vl.add

In the scripting part your should not use <> for tuples.
The following model works fine:
tuple Combination_L {
  int rooms;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int courses;
};


{Combination_L} L = {<1,2,3,4>,<2,3,4,5>};


tuple Combination_T {
  int days;
  int slots;
};


{Combination_T} T = {<10,11>,<12,13>};

tuple Combination_L_T{
  int rooms;
  int days;
  int slots;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int courses;
};

{Combination_L_T} Vl = {};
execute {
 for (var p in L){
   for (var q in T){
     Vl.add(p.rooms, 
             q.days,
             q.slots, 
             p.instructors, 
             p.studentgroups,
             p.courses);
   };
 }; 
};

NB:
As can be seen at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/cartesianproduct2.mod you can do that product in the modeling part too
